# Удаление Item'a QGraphicsScene C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, graphics

Вопрос заключается в следующем - инициализировал QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse и обозначил его на QGraphicsScene, как корректно будет удалить этот эллипс со сцены?

Answer (score 2):

Если удалить совсем, то можно просто `delete`'ом (Qt позаботится о всех потомках и об уведомлении сцены), а если только из сцены (и в дальнейшем его зачем-то ещё использовать), то `QGraphicsScene::removeItem()`.

Comment: Дело в том, что delete пробовал использовать, получаю ошибку <<malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeec820450: pointer being freed was not allocated>>
А removeItem работает с объектами типа QGraphicsItem, но не QGraphicsEllipseItem (Line, Rect) и так далее ;(

Comment: @Marshal, Не согласен, QGraphicsItem предок для QGraphicsEllipseItem, поэтому removeItem подходит и для всех потомков.

Comment: Ну, я могу что-то понимать, но тем не менее компилятор либо жалуется на тип, либо <<call to a non-static member function without an object argument>>

Comment: @Marshal, значит что-то не так делаешь, добавь код к вопросу (создание, удаление и, если есть, какие-то необычные промежуточные действия)... [mcve]

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну, в общем и целом я инициализирую саму сцену scene = new QGraphicsScene(this)
Момент следующий - у меня есть класс точки, который, помимо координат, в паблике хранит QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse и функцию draw, принимающую в себя сцену, на которой будет сам эллипс рисовать
В этом же классе я хотел сделать функцию удаления эллипса, void Point::remove() { QGraphicsScene::removeItem(this->ellipse); delete this->ellipse; }

Comment: @Marshal, все ключевые моменты стоит в виде кода добавить в вопрос... текстом всё равно ничего не понятно...